# How to fix DHCP and TFTP server?

Tags: dhcp, init.d, tftp

I do a job in which I need TFTP and DHCP server.

The DHCP settings I should adjust is (I have DHCP and DHCP 3, not sure where to set):

```
    default-lease-time 21600;
    max-lease-time 43200;
    option domain-name-servers 10.0.0.1;
    option netbios-name-servers 10.0.0.1;
    option netbios-node-type 8;
    option www-server 10.0.0.1;
    authoritative;
    allow booting;
    allow bootp;

    subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0
    {
    option routers 10.0.0.1;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    option broadcast-address 10.0.0.255;
    filename "/tftpboot/newsistemgeminis";
    range 10.0.0.10 10.0.0.100;
    }
```

I have to copy ''newsistemgeminis'' kernel image to the /tftpboot/.

For the TFTP server should edit /etc/inetd.conf and set the server directory to 
/tftpboot/ but this file is empty :/

I installed the following packages: dhcpd, tftp, tftpd-hpa, isc-dhcp-server

Now, start TFTP and DHCP, but I have these problems:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# invoke-rc.d dhcp start
 invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/dhcp not found.
```

I do not understand what happens, for more I seek not solve the problem, could someone please help me? I'll be very grateful, thanks and greetings.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to edit the `/etc/inetd.conf` file if you're going to use the default `/var/lib/tftpboot/` path. TFTP will default to this path already.

Typically the lines in your dhcpd.conf should be something like

```
next-server (ip address of tftp server); #this is if your tftp sever is separate from your DHCP server
filename "pxelinux.0";
```

`pxelinux.0` will typically point to a boot image in `pxelinux.conf` for the machine you're trying to boot.

For a completely overblown example of how this is put into practice, you can check out something like [Foreman](http://theforeman.org/), [MAAS](http://maas.ubuntu.com/), or any other orchestration tool.